# Deleting row data from view table mysql

Tags: php, mysql

how can i delete the view row, without hampering the underlying table in php? It's not working as expected.

```
public function deleteDataFromPreAllocation($data) {
    foreach($data as $student) {
        DB::delete('delete from PreAllocation where CID = ?' ,[$student->CID]);
    }
    $preAllocationData = DB::select("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PreAllocation");

    return $preAllocationData;
}
```

Comment: Please could you supply a bit more detail?  What's not working as expected?  'without hampering the underlying table' - what do you mean?

Comment: It may also be useful to know what you have coded in the `DB::delete()` method

Comment: It seems a little unnecessary to have a `select` and `delete` method into which you have to pass a query that has to contain the `SELECT` and `DELETE`

Comment: Maybe `delete from PreAllocation where CID in` would perform better? Not really clear what your current issue is

Comment: Also you are using mysql or mongodb? Is react relevant to your question? JS was not relevant.

Comment: Please  dont spam TAGS, they are there to attract the correct audience for your question. If you add IRRELEVANT TAGS all you do is gather an angry mob carrying torches and pitch forks

Answer (score 1):

First thing I noticed is that you have a single query in a loop, I'd firstly change that to a single query where the primary key is in an array.  Something like:

```
DELETE FROM PreAllocation WHERE CID IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

This is then a single query rather than multiple queries being run, much faster!

When you talk about the "view" I presume you have created a MySQL "view" from a table with a query.

For example if the table was a "people" which contained all of the people permitted to enter a university you could create a "view" called "students" based on the table "people" where the records in "people" had a field called "role" and was equal to "student".  Your view now contains all of the students in the university.  While not a real table you can effectively treat it as one.

If this is what you meant, the data you are deleting is not from the view but the actual table the view is based on.  So any changes made to the view and also mirrored in the table - you can't delete from one and not the other.